# Can I use cache manifest while I am online?

Tags: html, cache-manifest

I need to store my js files on browser to reduce load time.
I know that I can use local storage but its not proper way of storing files on browser , its made to store data not files.
Cache manifest we can use , but can I access it while I am online?

Also can specify if there is any better way to store js/css files on browser.

Comment: Yes, even when online, the cached files will be used as appropriate.

Comment: Can you please link some example , or link.

Answer (score 1):

Your JavaScript files will be automatically stored in browser caches according to normal cache principles and procedures, see http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/

You can use a cacheability tester like http://www.ircache.net/cgi-bin/cacheability.py to check the cacheability of a resource, including .js files.

The so-called cache manifest in HTML5 drafts is meant for use in *applications* that change rarely and can be used offline. For normal pages, it just makes things more complicated and risky.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML5 there is special feature for caching using  manifest file..
please visit following link..
http://html5doctor.com/go-offline-with-application-cache/
It will be helpful for you..